# Let PowerShell autocomplete cli parameter

Tags: powershell, autocomplete

Suppose I write a simple script that takes `$name`  as a cli parameter and print it. I know that when I invoke the script it can autocomplete `-name`, but is it possible to give PowerShell a list of values from which to autocomplete the value assigned to `$name`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [ValidateSet()] feature for your parameter. It is used as such:

```
Function Test-Me{
Param(
    [ValidateSet("Matt","John","Andrew")][String]$Name
)
    "You designated $Name"
}
```

Then when you access the function and go to fill in the -Name argument it will pop out a list of applicable names from the list provided.

[image: Pop-Out List of Names]

Comment: That's great, thanks! Little problem: only works on 8.1, not on server 2012 R2. Any idea why? thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment until just now. I'm afraid that I do not know why it doesn't work on Server 2012 R2, I do not have a server available to me. Are you using the ISE in both cases? I think tab-completion should still work either way. Sorry, I can't really test on server.